# How to use JSON+Patch with BackboneJS nested model/collection?

Tags: json, backbone.js, nested, patch

My data model is look like the following JSON structure (just example):

```
var post = {
  id: 123,
  title: 'Sterling Archer',    
  comments: [
    {text: 'Comment text', tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']},
    {text: 'Comment test', tags: ['tag2', 'tag5']}
  ]  
};
```

In Backbone side it represented as nested model that looks likes the following:

```
var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   parse: function (response) {
       if (response.comments) {
          response.comments = new Backbone.Collection(response.comments);
       }
       return response;
   }
});

var post = new PostModel(post, {parse: true});
```

I want to apply [rfc6902 (JSONPatch) specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) to my structure. But the problem here is that my structure is not pure JSON but nested model/collection units.

I need best practices about how could I patch my nested backbonejs structure like in official documentation [examples](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#appendix-A):

Does anybody has experience in using JSON+Patch specification in your BackboneJS applications? Please share with us.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** here is the short example. Let's say I need to make some modifications on my post model like comment adding:

```
var op = [
  { "op": "add", "path": "/comments/2", "value":  {text: 'Comment test3', tags: ['tag4']}" }
]
```

How could I do it with backbone:

```
post.appyPatch(op);
```

Is there any best practices or/and backbone extensions for do it?

Comment: Not clear on what you're trying to accomplish with PATCH, but it seems to me that you'll want to override the model's toJSON method to translate the structure back to valid JSON regardless.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the post

Comment: The `async` method in `Backbone` does not support this type of request unfortunately. You could always extend it yourself. That would be the `best practice` IMHO. You could always look at [this JSON patch library](http://jsonpatchjs.com/) and get some cues.

Answer (score 4):

I've created a working app here in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/p9PX2NBrVwki7EaA1wEt?p=preview) using the shared code and [json-patch.js](https://www.npmjs.org/package/json-patch) library for applying the patch. I've extended `PostModel` with `applyPatch` method which applies the patch. Here is the `applyPatch` method code:

```
var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    ...    
    applyPatch: function(op) {
        var postStringify = JSON.stringify(this); // JSON string
        var postAttributesJSON = JSON.parse(postStringify); // JSON object. This is same as postAttributes
        var postPatched = jsonpatch.apply_patch(postAttributesJSON, op); // Patch applied
        var changed = this.changedAttributes(postPatched); // Changed attributes
        var self = this; 
        _.each(_.keys(changed), function(key) {
            if(key == 'comments') {
                self.get('comments').set(changed[key], {merge: true});
            }
        }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I see the following problems in your code: 1. After `this.set(postPatched)` I lose comments Collection. 2. It's not efficient to replace whole model after applying patch. It could be better it we can update specific unit of nested model. In my example it's just add new model into 'comments' collection instead replacing one. Do you have any thoughts about it?

Comment: Sorry I missed out on nested collection. It may not be possible to have **generalized** functionality on nested collections. I've modified the app in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/p9PX2NBrVwki7EaA1wEt?p=preview). Let me know whether it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I thought that is possible to make it for any nested model without knowledge about these name (like 'comments').